# HTML email - extra padding in cell in Firefox & hotmail on PC

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I'm trying to style a HTML email, obviously using tables and inline styles. I'm testing using litmus .com

I'm getting pretty good consistent results, apart from on 2 clients - Hotmail & Gmail on Firefox.

I'm embedding a table in a cell, here's the html for the embedded table -

```
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding:0px;">  
<tr>
<td colspan="3" valign="bottom" style="font-size:0px; padding:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:bottom;overflow:hidden; "><img src="/images/promo-border-top.jpg" width="221" height="4"></td>

<td rowspan="4" style="padding-left:20px; ">
<a href=""><img name="template_r8_c2" src="/images/shop-now-eng.png" width="118" height="32" border="0" id="template_r8_c2" alt="shop now" /></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" height="24" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;  height:24px; background-image:url(/images/promo-border-left.jpg);background-repeat:repeat-y; background-position:left; overflow:hidden;" ><img src="/images/promo-border-left.jpg" width="4" height="24"></td>
 <td align="center" valign="middle" height="20" style="padding:0px; height:20px; overflow:hidden; line-height:10px; font-family: arial, helvetica; color: #333333;  font-size:12px margin-bottom:1px;">xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx</td>
 <td align="right" height="24" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;  height:24px; background-image:url(/images/promo-border-right.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-y; background-position:right;"><img src="/images/promo-border-right.jpg" width="4" height="24"></td>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="3" valign="top" style="padding:0px; font-size:0px; margin:0px; height:4px; background-color:yellow;overflow:hidden;"><img src="images/promo-border-bottom.jpg" width="221" height="4"></td>        
  </table>
```

I've put two images below of how it's rendering - ignore the yellow bit, that was added for testing.

[image: This is how it should look, and how it looks across most clients]

[image: This is how it looks in hotmail and gmail]

Comment: Apologies, it was rendering out the table rather than showing the code. Fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `display:block` to your images. [GMail likes to add a little margin to images](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3132/how-to-stop-gmail-from-adding-a-margin-to-your-images/) that are displayed `inline`, the default.

EDIT: Based on the comment below: it looks like there's a `td` with a `rowspan` of 4 and only 3 possible rows in your `table`. What if you changed that 4 to a 3?

Comment: Take a look at my edit. Could be due to an extra row that you're trying to span that's not there.

Answer (score 0):

In the table try adding `style="line-height:50%;display:block;"`

Sometimes if you have a table cell that is just a single image it will add extra padding despite your attempts to set it to zero.

I'm just a beginner when it comes to HTML, but this worked when I was having a similar problem.